# Migrating oracle 6i to 10g web performance problems

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms, migrating

We have recently migrated Oracle 6i forms with a native runtime to 10g to work with web and java. It works but with huge performance problems. For example, in the server which is running red hat, switching between two screens in the web version 10g uses 15% cpu per client!!!

This is crazy and must be an error somewhere, because we have other applications running in 10g which was "made" for web but never existed in 6i, but switching normally between a screen is something like 0.5-2% cpu use, not 15% or even 20% like this is giving us.

What gives? Is there something we are missing in the migration between 6i and 10g here? If anyone has any idea, be it configuration or code etc please do tell!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean 9i?  Or is there really such a thing as 6i?  I don't recall the internet being such a big deal when Oracle 6 was around...

Comment: He is right...the version of Forms was 6i, which corresponded in the time frame of Oracle DB 9i. With Forms 10g they "evened out" the versions so that the App server releases corresponded with the Database releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What settings do you have for things
  like heartBeat in formsweb.cfg?
- What version of App server are you on (10g-9.0.4, 10gR2-10.1.2.x, etc)?
- Since this is linux, is this 32 or 64
  and if it is 64 are you running it
  with linux32 like the documentation
  says?
- On the clients, are you using JInitiator or the Java JRE and what OS are your clients?